# How can I dispatch 'payment_method_is_active' from controller?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, payment-methods

I have a payment_method_is_active event in Magento. I'm trying to dispatch from controller with:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('payment_method_is_active', array(
                    'result' =>$this->getResult(),
                    'method'          => $method,
                    'quote'           => $quote
                ));
```

but it is not working(doesn't even get in observer).
I suppose I don't get array variables right. So, how can I do?

Comment: please provide your config code and also full code of your observer

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137254/dispatch-magento-event-with-ajax/137349#137349